# Import method failure in secp256k1 in Rust

Tags: rust, secp256k1

I am trying to use the function `new_with_hash` from `secp256k1::ecdh::SharedSecret` in Rust

but I am getting this error

```
no function or associated item named `new_with_hash` found for struct `SharedSecret` in the current scope
```

It seems like the function does not exist anymore. Is there a direct replacement for this method in the new version?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this PR](https://github.com/rust-bitcoin/rust-secp256k1/pull/402) it was changed to a free function:

> Pulls the `new_with_hash` logic out into a standalone public function that just returns the 64 bytes representing the x,y co-ordinates of the computed shared secret point. Callers are then responsible for hashing this point to get the shared secret

This new function is: [shared_secret_point](https://docs.rs/secp256k1/0.27.0/secp256k1/ecdh/fn.shared_secret_point.html):

> Creates a shared point from public key and secret key.
>
> Can be used like `SharedSecret` but caller is responsible for then hashing the returned buffer. This allows for the use of a custom hash function since `SharedSecret` uses SHA256.

You can read the PR comments for more about the motivation for the change.